# How to Decide if I should upgrade the Ubuntu Server

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, tomcat, ubuntu-10.10

I am using AWS micro instance running Apache HTTP Server and Tomcat servers. I have couple of Web Apps deployed on them where I use port forwarding from 80 to 8080 using Apache. Since I work for a startup (not a sysadmin, and willing to learn), I have to figure out whether we need to upgrade the server from micro to some other instance.

What benchmarks should I check to see if I should update the server?
I checked free -m which gives about 300mb of free memory.

But what else should I check to see if the number of connections that Apache is receiving isn't choking it at anytime. Since I use port forwarding how do I check if the Tomcat connections are choking or not.

300mb Free memory is at the instance of time when I checked. But other times when the system may have load, how do I check that?

Answer (score 1):

You should setup monitoring tools to get detailed information on how your server and application is performing.

Also, you shouldn't use micro instances for production servers.

### Use Case

http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/

> Low traffic websites or blogs, small administrative applications,
>   bastion hosts, and free trials to explore EC2 functionality (t1.micro
>   only)

### CPU Considerations

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/concepts_micro_instances.html

> Micro instances (t1.micro) provide a small amount of consistent CPU
>   resources and allow you to increase CPU capacity in short bursts when
>   additional cycles are available. They are well suited for lower
>   throughput applications and websites that require additional compute
>   cycles periodically.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623050/amazon-m1-small-vs-micro-instance-cpu-perfomance

> In my testing, I've found that consuming 100% CPU for about 10-15
>   seconds on a micro instance, gets you throttled down to a fraction of
>   that -- approximately 0.2 ECU -- for about the next 2-3 minutes, when
>   the throttling lifts for a few seconds, then the cycle repeats

### Network Speed Considerations

http://epamcloud.blogspot.com.au/2013/03/testing-amazon-ec2-network-speed.html

micro's have significantly bandwidth available to them